# Chasper in Jean de Florette

Tags: vocabulaire, orthographe

Dans *Jean de Florette* de Pagnol, Attilio écrit à Ugolin :

> Je t’ai pas répondu de suite pourquoi ma sœur s’est marié avec Egidio, celui qui la chaspait tout le temps. Mintenant, s’est son droit.

The whole letter is full of amusing misspellings. But I find it hard to reconcile my best guess, *chasser*, with an extra *p* — all the other misspellings still phonetically align with the pronunciation (*toultan*, *samarive*). Also, *chasser* doesn't really match the context, which seems to require "tease" or "pester", not "run after", if he has the right to *chasper* now that he's married.

So is there a verb *chasper* or something that sounds like it in Provençal ? Or do they dissimilate the double *s* in words? What else could account for this?

(Also, this is a second question, but to shoehorn it in: pourquoi *pourquoi* ? Is it used like *parce que* in Provence?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really another verb with a wide range of meanings meaning basically "to touch".

> ([Dictionnaire Vivant de la Langue Française](https://dvlf.uchicago.edu/mot/chasper) CHASPER, [oser? draguer?] ; **caresser, peloter**.
> • Vas-y, que je te dis... Vas-y ! Chaspe, mon vieux. Chaspe... (1953).
>
> (Provence, Midi) **Tripoter**
> Contribuée le 9 Février 2018

Here is much more information: [chasper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qF8TYQpG8cU)

Good guess !

[Pourquoi](http://jcautran.free.fr/provencal/lexique_p.html) Adverbe souvent utilisé à la place de parce que. Cela tient à l'ambivalence du *perqué* provençal (qui signifie à la fois pourquoi et parce que), tout comme celle de l'italien perche ou de l'espagnol *porque* :
• « Tu dois pas traverser cette rue, pourquoi c'est défendu ».
• « Pourquoi faut pas dire de gros mots ? », demande l'enfant. « Pourquoi c'est pas joli ! », réponds la mère.
Ou encore :
• « J'ai manqué l'école, pourquoi je suis été un peu malade... ».

[Lexique des termes provençaux et des « mots d'ici »](http://jcautran.free.fr/provencal/lexique_provencal.html#ANCRE1)

Comment: Ah! I should have guessed that about 'pourquoi' given what I know of Spanish.